# Custom non-common filesystem for embedded linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, embedded

My embedded linux gets its data files from an external source (sd card).  As this media is easily detachable I'd like to protect it in a certain way.

First idea that comes in mind is to do encryption.  I'm afraid though this would take too much processing power.  My files are not deeply sensitive, but I don't want that people can put the card into their desktop and see/copy my files.  I assume these people know how to mount a standard ext4 drive.

Content is initially loaded on to the disk via a desktop linux box, so the process should be

I wouldn't care too much if the solution is not hack-proof.  Basically I want to avoid to have my content copied by the general copycat.

I'm not looking for a turn-key solution, but like to get some pointers into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

A simple [XOR Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) requires very little processing.  The security is limited in the sense that if someone has a both the encrypted and plain-text data, by XOR'ing the two the encryption key is revealed.  However so long as you can avoid someone being knowingly in possession of both, and the key itself remains confidential, it may meet your requirements of simplicity and security.

Obviously you need a longer key that the simple 8 bit one in the example in the link.  The key itself can be arbitrarily long with no impact on performance.

Comment: Your solution will cipher files on a standard readable file system.  However I'm looking for a ciphered file system which - after proper mounting - offers standard file access.